# mouseClicked without mousePressed

Tags: java, swing, adapter, mouse

I'm trying to make minesweeper with a basic GUI as a summer project and want to be able to shade the surrounding tiles when you click and hold a tile using Java Swing's MouseAdapter

```
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){ // shades surrounding tiles
                    for (int rowOff = tileLoc.row() - 1; rowOff < tileLoc.row() + 2; rowOff++) {
                        for (int colOff =  (tileLoc.col() - 1); colOff < tileLoc.col() + 2; colOff++) {
                            // TODO add validTile()
                            allTiles[rowOff][colOff].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                        }
                    }
                }
                @override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){ 
                     // undoes shading & clicks tile
                }
```

(TileLoc is a Record with 2 values, row and col)
This code works the way I want it to but the issue is that it's also getting called on the mouseClicked()

```
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){ // 1 is left click, 3 is right click
                    switch (e.getButton()){
                        case 1:
                             //does board.leftClick()
                        case 3:
                            //does board.rightClick()
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

How can I make the mouseClicked() not shade and unshade the tiles?

Comment: `mouseClicked` is called when the release of the mouse is at the same (or close to) spot the mouse was pressed.  This means that it's not easily distinguishable.  One idea might be to capture the time of the "press" and when clicked is called, calculate the duration between the two events and then make a determination about what to do based on the amount of time which has passed

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with a timer variable. When the mouse is pressed save the current time to a class variable `pressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();`:

```
long pressedTime = -1;

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){ // shades surrounding tiles
    pressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //Your code here...
    //...
}
```

Now we can change the behaviour of the mouseReleased and mouseClicked methods to account for this timer, and take action accordingly:

```
@override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){ 
     //Find the time difference
     long timeDifference = System.currentTimeMillis() - pressedTime;

     //If the held time is long enough do the held action
     if(timeDifferenec > yourRequiredTime){
         //Do something
     }

    //Else if the click was shorter than your hold time then manage your click like normal:
     else{
         switch (e.getButton()){
            case 1:
                 //does board.leftClick()
            case 3:
                //does board.rightClick()
                break;
            default:
                break;
     }
}

//Do nothing in the mouseClicked event, we can manage this entirely in the mouse released event
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
     //Nothing here
}
```

Note that depending on the situation that you use this in, and if you share the variable with multiple functions/buttons, then you might want to reset the value of `pressedTime` to -1 after clicks, and check for a -1 value before taking any actions.

Answer (score 0):

A mouseclick consists of pressing and releasing the button on the same location. You want to react on mouseclicked - at this point in time you do not know when the user releases the button.

So make up your mind: Do you want to react immediately? I think that's what you already have. Do you want to react delayed? (That's what sorifiend suggests.) And what happens if the user releases the button after a long time but at the same location: Was that a slow click, or does it mean something different?

All solutions work to the requirement that the adjoining fields are highlighted when the user presses the mouse button.